# Pandas - Aggregate by each possible combination of keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame Pandas, which I'd like to group by data the most possible with combinations of columns A, B, C and D.

Let's say it has this form:

```
      A   B   C   D   E   F   G        
0     Y   X   Y   Z   1   2   7
1     Y   X   Y   Z   3   4   8 
2     X   Y   U   V   1   1   1
3     X   Y   V   U   1   2   0
4     X   Z   Z   Z   1   8   1
```

First, I try to group by at higher level, so I try to group by ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']. For the rows that haven't been regrouped, I try lower combinations like ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], and so on. Finally I am using no combination but just grouping by ['A'] then ['B'] then ['C'] then ['D']. At this point, I have grouped data with each possible aggregation key implying A, B, C and D.

With this method, the desired output would be:

```
      A   B   C   D           
0     Y   X   Y   Z    
1     X   Y     
2     X
```

Is it possible to do these operations easily?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve. Please post some input data and desired output. Your current input data is just an empty dataframe

Comment: Yes. I modified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first all combination of columns values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   })

print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  5  4  7  1
1  3  5  8  3
2  6  4  9  5
3  9  5  4  7
4  2  5  2  1
5  4  4  3  0

from  itertools import combinations
a = df.columns
comb = [j for i in range(len(a), 0, -1) for j in combinations(a,i)]
print (comb)
[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D'), 
 ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D'), 
('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',)]

a = pd.concat([df.loc[:, x].sum(axis=1) for x in comb], axis=1)
print (a)
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
0  17  16  10  13  12   9  12   6  11   5   8   5   4   7   1
1  19  16  11  14  16   8  11   6  13   8  11   3   5   8   3
2  24  19  15  20  18  10  15  11  13   9  14   6   4   9   5
3  25  18  21  20  16  14  13  16   9  12  11   9   5   4   7
4  10   9   8   5   8   7   4   3   7   6   3   2   5   2   1
5  11  11   8   7   7   8   7   4   7   4   3   4   4   3   0
```

Then get all duplicates by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and get firast `True`s by [`numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
print (pd.concat([df.duplicated(x, keep=False) for x in comb], axis=1))

      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9   \
0   True   True   True   True   True   True   True   True   True   True   
1   True   True   True   True   True   True   True   True   True   True   
2  False  False  False  False  False   True  False  False  False  False   
3  False  False  False  False  False   True  False  False  False  False   
4  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   

      10    11     12     13     14  
0   True  True   True   True   True  
1   True  True   True   True   True  
2  False  True   True  False  False  
3  False  True   True  False  False  
4  False  True  False  False   True  

a = pd.concat([df.duplicated(x, keep=False) for x in comb], axis=1).values.argmax(axis=1)
print (a)
[ 0  0  5  5 11]
```

Last use this array as argument for `groupby`:

```
df = df.groupby(a).sum()
print (df)
    E  F   G
0   4  6  15
5   2  3   1
11  1  8   1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I realize I haven't been clear. I wanted to group data by all combinations possible, from higher to lower level, using function groupBy