# Efficiently go through Python Pandas columns combinations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe `df` and each column can only be True/False.

I want to iterate through all possible combinations of 2 columns and basically do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import os
import random
import itertools 

# Test dataframe
input_list = [True,False,True]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col0':input_list},index=[1,2,3])
for i in range(1,100):
    random.shuffle(input_list)
    df['col{}'.format(i)]=input_list

def test_func(df):
    return df

# Iteration starts here
start_time = time.time()
for col1, col2 in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2):
    output = df.loc[(df[col1]==True) & (df[col2]==True)]
    ret = test_func(output)
print(time.time()-start_time)
```

I am wondering what is the most efficient way of doing so when the number of column combination is huge. Currently I am doing it using `itertools.combinations` and `for` loops as shown above. And the possible improvement I can think of is to incapsulate the above code in a function and call multiprocess.Pool with map.

```
def incasulate_fun(df,col1,col2):
    output = df.loc[(df[col1]==True) & (df[col2]==True)]
    return function(output)
```

df is relatively small and can fit into memory. My expectation is that I can get a roughly 4 times speed up if having a 4 core machine and if memory is not an issue. Appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: `df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])` "splits" your DataFrame into all unique combinations of [col1, col2] that exist in your DataFrame. You can then `apply` your function to that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Aggregate by each possible combination of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881766/pandas-aggregate-by-each-possible-combination-of-keys)

Comment: I'm sure there's a dupe... but that isn't it.  I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

#### `itertools.combinations`/`pd.concat`

```
from itertools import combinations

pd.concat({(a, b): df[a] & df[b] for a, b in combinations(df.columns, 2)}, axis=1)

       A             B
       B      C      C
0  False   True  False
1  False  False  False
2   True  False  False
```

---

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]], range(3), [*'ABC'], dtype=bool)

df

       A      B      C
0   True  False   True
1  False   True  False
2   True   True  False
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion! But I guess your implementation is similar to what I am doing atm (see edited) and I won't expect big performance difference. I would expect some parallelism could help.

Comment: Truth is, I put this together in 2-ish minutes.  Not much of a time investment on my part.  However, to really give it a go to improve performance might take me 10 to 30 minutes of trying things.  I'd hate to do all that work only to not have it be what you needed/wanted.  So, could you do me a favor and read this link ==> [mcve] and edit your question such that I can easily see what you have and what you expect?  Thanks.

Comment: Included a small test case as you have suggested.

Comment: I see.  The only way to optimize that is to be very specific about the operations you are doing in `test_func` and/or what is going into `output` (if it's different than what you're showing).  Straight up iteration can't get more efficient than what you're doing unless you optimize the functions themselves or integrate the function into the loop.  We can't do that here unless we have more specifics.